# how to convert from strings to int and split them character by character into another array

Tags: php

Using this function,`prt_pattern("341","0")`, to print out

```
 0 
00 
00 
000
```

I'm stuck at converting `"341"` into integer and store it each number the following was the result i wanted

```
array[0] = 3
array[1] = 4
array[2] = 1
```

The flow I'm going to plan for this function is, convert string into int and store it by character, and then find the highest value. After that using `2 for loop`, 1st for loop is loop from largest number to 1 and 2nd loop is for looping the number if `4 = 4`, print `0` else print `" "` and value at `array[1] -= 1`.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: what did you so far?

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar : I was stuck on changing the string to int and store it individual.

Comment: Why do you want to change the string to int first? Use `str_split()` to split the string into digits first, then convert each digit to an int.

Comment: @RussJ: as i mention, I'm stuck at converting from str to int and store in an array. Which is the first step of the function.

Comment: And in PHP you often don't need to convert to int explicitly. If you use a string in a context that needs a number, it will be converted automatically.

Comment: @Barmar: Cool. Thanks! I din't know it will be converted automatic. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work. First I create an array of each number inside the string (cast to integer), then find the highest number from it using the `max` function.

```
<?php
$array = (function ($str): array {
    $a = [];
    $strlen = strlen($str);
    for($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
        $a[] = (int) $str[$i];
    }
    return $a;
})("3429");


var_dump($array);

/**
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(9)
}
**/

var_dump(max($array)); //int(9)
```

Test it online here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e3446d4475c3d69215857ed33a2c1f94f628e0b

*edit*

As `Barmar` pointed out in the comments, its way easier to use PHPs function `str_split` like so:

```
$array = str_split("3429");
```

Which will create an array just like previous mentioned.

(I feel silly for not thinking of that function.)

Comment: Any reason you're not using `str_split()`?

Comment: Yes, I didnt think of it honestly. I'll update the answer.

Comment: After using `str_split()`, continue with `$array = (int) $array`. It will convert str to int? @Barmar @paskl

Comment: After ```str_split``` you'll have an array just like with the previous answer. With ```max($array)``` you get the highest number from that array.

Comment: @LonelyToh You can use `$array = array_map('intval', $array)` to convert all the elements of `$array` to integers.